# ANSI C - direct-declarator grammar - Why does the C grammar allow syntactically legal, but sementically illegal declarations like int func()()?

Tags: c, syntax, grammar, declaration, c89

The ANSI C grammar specifies:

```
declarator:
    pointer_opt direct-declarator

direct-declarator:
    identifier
    ( declarator )
    direct-declarator [ constant-expression_opt ]
    direct-declarator ( parameter-type-list )
    direct-declarator ( identifier-list_opt )
```

According to this grammar, it would be possible to derive

```
func()()
```

as a declarator, and

```
int func()()
```

as a declaration, which is semantically illegal. Why does the C grammar allow such syntactically legal, but sementically illegal declarations?

Comment: Is this really about C89? Put language lawyer in there instead?

Comment: A related part of the grammar is `pointer:` —
`* type-qualifier-listopt` – `* type-qualifier-listopt pointer` and `type-qualifier-list:` — `type-qualifier` – `type-qualifier-list type-qualifier`.  These allow you an unlimited number of type qualifiers for each pointer (`const`, `volatile`, `restrict`), but that doesn't mean it makes sense to write 30 of them in row.  Yes, you're right at one level, but it is mostly irrelevant.  (Digits in a number is another place where there's no limit in the grammar.  …)

Comment: This grammar is effectively the same in C11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the C grammar allow syntactically legal, but semantically illegal declarations like int func()()?

Your question basically answers itself:
Quite simply, it's because it's a grammar's whole *job* to accept syntactically legal constructs.  If something is syntactically legal, but semantically meaningless or illegal, it's not the grammar's job to reject it -- it gets rejected later, during semantic analysis.

And if the question is, "Why wasn't the grammar written differently, so that semantically illegal constructs were also syntactically illegal (such that the grammar could reject them)?", the answer is that it's often a tradeoff whether to reject things during parsing or during semantic analysis.  C's declaration syntax is pretty complicated, and there's an obvious desire to make the grammar which accepts it about as complicated as, but not significantly more complicated than, it has to be.  Often, you can keep a grammar nicely simple by deferring certain checks to the semantic analysis phase.

Answer (score 6):

These kinds of questions typically can't be answered for certain, because you're asking for information about the collective thoughts and deliberations of the C committee, *in 1989*.  They've never conducted the work of language development wholly in public, the way, say, the people responsible for Python do, and thirty years ago they did that even less.  And if you polled them personally, they probably wouldn't remember.

We can look at the [C Rationale document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) (I'm linking to the edition corresponding to C1999, but as far as I know it didn't change very much since 1989) for clues, but on a quick skim, I don't see anything relevant to your question.

That leaves me making guesses based on general principles of programming language design.  There *is* a general principle relevant to your question: Particularly for older languages, designers try to make the formal syntax be [context-free](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~nelson/courses/csc_173/grammars/cfg.html) as much as possible.  This makes it much easier to write an efficient parser.  Rules like "you can't have a function that returns a function" require context, and so they are left out of the syntax.  It's straightforward to handle them as post-hoc constraints applied to the parse tree instead, so that's what designers do.

The C grammar has a whole bunch of places where this principle appears to have been used, not just the one you're asking about.  For instance, the "maximal munch" rule for tokenization exists because it means the tokenizer does not need to be aware of the full parser context, even though it leads to inconvenient results, such as `a-----b` being interpreted as `a -- -- - b` instead of `a -- - -- b`, even though the parser will reject the former but accept the latter.

This design principle for programming languages is often surprising to beginners, because it's so different from how humans understand natural languages; we will go out of our way to "repair" some kind of contextually appropriate meaning from even the most nonsensical sentences, and we actually [*rely* on this](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/implicature/) in conversation.  It might help to contemplate the meta-principle that [worse is better](https://www.dreamsongs.com/WorseIsBetter.html) (to oversimplify, because you can get the first 90% of the work done quickly and put it out there and then iterate on the remaining 90%).

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarifying answer.

Comment: If it weren't for typedefs, it would be reasonably straightforward to write a context-free grammar which disallowed functions whose return type was a function or an array. The grammar would be more complicated, but it wouldn't have to be context-sensitive. However, since you can alias an array or function type, the semantic restriction would still be necessary in order to prevent `ArrayType foo(void);` from being valid. Since the extra-grammatic restriction is required anyway, there is little point complicating the grammar (even more than it already is).

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the C grammar allow such syntactically legal, but sementically illegal declarations?

What makes you think it sensible to expect the language syntax to be unable to express any semantically incorrect statements?

Not all semantic problems can even be detected at compile time (example: `y = 1 / x;`, which is well-defined except when `x` is zero).  Even formulating the syntax rules so that they do not accept any statements, declarations, or expressions that can be proven semantically wrong at compile time would be of little benefit.  It would complicate the syntax rules tremendously for very little gain, as compilers have to do the semantic analysis either way.

Note well that the primary audience for the language standard is *people*, not machines.  That's why it describes the language semantics with prose.